# Dictionaries: Random keys and random number of items from key's list

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have this int to list key/value pairs dictionary.

`PrimNeighboursDict = {883: [880, 881, 884], 884: [883, 885], 885: [884, 886, 889], 886: [885, 889, 887, 888]}`

I want to select a certain number of keys randomly and then for each selected key's list, i want to select a certain number of items randomly from those lists.

e.g.

```
randomly selected keys:
883,885
randomly select number of items from each key's list:
883: 881
885: 884,889
```

This is what i have so far, i have randomly selected keys:

```
import random

PrimNeighboursDict = {883: [880, 881, 884], 884: [883, 885], 885: [884, 886, 889], 886: [885, 889, 887, 888]}
randomPrimitiveFilter = node.evalParm('RandomPrimitiveFilter') #a slider to control the number of selected keys

dictlength = len(PrimNeighboursDict) #dictionary length so total number of primitives

for primitives,neighbours in PrimNeighboursDict.items(): 
    d = PrimNeighboursDict.fromkeys(range(dictlength))
    keys = random.sample(list(d), randomPrimitiveFilter)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the literal value `2` instead of your slider value because I don't have the slider. If I understand your question correctly, you need 2 steps.

1. Choose 2 random keys from the dictionary.
2. For each chosen key, choose two random values from the associated
   list.

So,

```
randomPrimitiveFilter = 2
# Step 1
sample_keys = random.sample(PrimNeighboursDict.keys(),randomPrimitiveFilter)
# Step 2
for k in sample_keys:
    sample_values = random.sample(PrimNeighboursDict[k],randomPrimitiveFilter)
    print k, sample_values
```

This gives me (every run will of course differ)

```
886 [885, 887]
884 [883, 885]
```